# Rubymine cursor control and Enter key do not work on remote host

Tags: intellij-idea, ssh, rubymine, enter

I run Rubymine IDE for a remote project (Ubuntu 20.04) via ssh. I use file menu Item called remote development and then chose ssh connection.   Local machine is Windows 11. Hitting cursor controls left, right, up, down, Backspace, and most annoyingly, the Enter key seem do not cause anything during text editing, though they work on local projects and for menu navigation. Any fixes or workarounds? At the moment I use context copy-paste to enter new lines.

PS. Due to corporate firewall I use an intermediate jump server and forward port 22 to a local port.

Update. I used an older license, trial or beta. I renewed license and after recent update to RubyMine 2023.1 RC (March 23) on client and remote cursor works fine. Also 2022.3.3 worked (from WSL2 though UX seems better on win). It seems also best run the same version on local and remote. Did not try official 2023.1 yet.

Comment: Just to be sure, do you connect via Gateway or not? Meaning, does RubyMine run on the local machine or on the remote as well?

Comment: I understand that local RubyMine launches server instance